# my mutex doesn't work perfectly. I have problem reading data

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

I have a multithreading program in C#. It reads a list of files. After reading relevant file, the thread done its task and finished. I have an array of threads, because I have memory limit. After current thread terminated, I started mew reading file in same thread. My problem is: Although I use a mutex, thread entered in and increase my file counter and I read more than 10 files (here in code, for example). I don’t know why…

I tried use a lock or monitor instead of mutex, but it don’t fix the problem.

I add  after code the print output.

```
    readonly Mutex m1 = new Mutex();
    int thIdx = 0, thAll = 0;
    List<string> file_l = new List<string>();
    Thread[,] arr = new Thread[4, 2];


    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cDev; i++)
        {
                for (int j = 0; j < cTrd; j++)
                {
                    int xi = i, xj = j;
                    StartThread(xi, xj);
                }
            }
    }               


    private void StartThread(int i, int j)
    {
        arr[i, j] = new Thread(() => Busy(i, j));
        arr[i, j].Start();

        Console.WriteLine($"started T[{i},{j}]    StartTime = {DateTime.Now}.{DateTime.Now.Ticks}");
        thIdx++;
        thAll++;
    }

    private void CriticalSection(Mutex m, DelegateType fun)
    {            
        m.WaitOne();
        try
        {
            /* critical code */
            fun();
        }
        finally
        {
            m.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }


      bool doneAll = false;

    private void Busy(int i, int j)
    {
        // get file index for executind
        int k = 0;
        int k1 = 0;

        // ** here is mutex and problem **
        CriticalSection(m1, () =>
        {
            k = db.GetFileID(); // do id++ in db
            k1 = k + 1;
            if (k1 == 10) //file_l.Count
            {
                doneAll = true;
            }
        });


        // Busy
        Console.WriteLine($"busy T[{i},{j}]          {k}  -  {file_l[k]}{i}{j}");
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        string exec = "";

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        Console.WriteLine($"finished T[{i},{j}]    * {k}  -   ({DateTime.Now - startTime})   -  command = {exec}");
        thIdx--;

        if (doneAll && thIdx == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"finished all  -   ({DateTime.Now - startTimeAll})   -   files = {thAll}");
            Console.WriteLine("end");
        }


        if (doneAll)
        {
            arr[i, j].Abort(); // release thread
        }
        else if (k1 < 10) 
        {
                StartThread(i, j);               
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
started T[0,0]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:19.637025941396299385

started T[0,1]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:19.637025941396339280

busy T[0,0]          0  -  3562634_04018610_2_CROP.MPG00

busy T[0,1]          1  -  6236814_04073221_1_CROP.MPG01

started T[3,0]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:19.637025941396359231

busy T[3,0]          2  -  5886591_04081109_2_CROP.MPG30

started T[3,1]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:19.637025941396379179

busy T[3,1]          3  -  3747967_04040496_3_CROP.MPG31

finished T[0,0]    * 0  -   (00:00:03.0278023)   -  command = sleep 3

finished T[3,0]    * 2  -   (00:00:03.0258075)   -  command = sleep 3

finished T[3,1]    * 3  -   (00:00:03.0238131)   -  command = sleep 3

started T[0,0]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:22.637025941426637254

finished T[0,1]    * 1  -   (00:00:03.0278023)   -  command = sleep 3

started T[3,0]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:22.637025941426647250

busy T[0,0]          4  -  3562909_04015124_3_CROP.MPG00

started T[3,1]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:22.637025941426687119

busy T[3,1]          5  -  6347131_04081352_1_CROP.MPG31

busy T[3,0]          6  -  4005567_04043606_4_CROP.MPG30

started T[0,1]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:22.637025941426766913

busy T[0,1]          7  -  4005566_04043601_2_CROP.MPG01

finished T[0,0]    * 4  -   (00:00:03.0055051)   -  command = sleep 3

started T[0,0]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:25.637025941456762049

busy T[0,0]          8  -  3562434_04040432_2_CROP.MPG00

finished T[3,1]    * 5  -   (00:00:03.0324275)   -  command = sleep 3

finished T[3,0]    * 6  -   (00:00:03.0284380)   -  command = sleep 3

started T[3,1]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:25.637025941457051293

finished T[0,1]    * 7  -   (00:00:03.0264398)   -  command = sleep 3

started T[3,0]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:25.637025941457081178

busy T[3,0]          9  -  3740413_04012542_2_CROP.MPG30

started T[0,1]    StartTime = 28/08/2019 13:02:25.637025941457160961

busy T[0,1]          10  -  3562404_04015032_2_CROP.MPG01

busy T[3,1]          11  -  5914063_04081061_1_CROP.MPG31

finished T[0,0]    * 8  -   (00:00:03.0058500)   -  command = sleep 3

finished T[3,0]    * 9  -   (00:00:03.0108370)   -  command = sleep 3

finished T[0,1]    * 10  -   (00:00:03.0310286)   -  command = sleep 3

finished T[3,1]    * 11  -   (00:00:03.0529614)   -  command = sleep 3

finished all  -   (00:00:09.1713083)   -   files = 12

end
```

I expect readind 10 files as in the condition, but it stopped after 12 files

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing, you might want to read [mcve]. But I think you should check inside the critical section if you are done reading files. Because if e.g. 3 threads are waiting to get the mutex and the thread currently holding the mutex sets `doneAll ` to `true`, then the other 3 threads waiting will at somepoint in time enter the cs and do its task.

Comment: thanks!! it work (with more little fix)

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is in db.GetFileID() function. You expect that value in db updated but seems it really doesn't. Try to control you threads count using global variable, not the result of this functon.